# Worst known algorithm in terms of Big-O (more precisely Big-theta)?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, algorithms

Hello,

I have been trying to find the worst algorithm in terms of it's Big-O function. By worst I mean n! is worse than n^2, n^n is worse than n!, etc. Essentially the worst algorithm would be the one with the fastest growing expression inside the Big-O notation.

I am aware that with the definition of Big-O if an algorithm is O(n^2), then it is also O(n!), so to be more precise I am really looking for the worst algorithm in terms of Big-Theta, because Big-Theta provides a more tight bound (I believe the tightest possible bound in terms of asymptotic analysis). I used Big-O in the title and explanation because I am not sure how many people are familiar with Big-Theta vs. Big-O.

I don't care at all from what branch of computing the algorithm is from (computational geometry, graph theory, etc.).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bogosort! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a real question. Isn't it the case that given any algorithm one can find another that's significantly worse?

Comment: @Gerry: you could ask the question: for what problem is the best running time given in the literature the maximum? 

Comment: Algorithms calculating the diagonal of the Ackermann function tend to be slow.

Comment: I really don't know much in this topic: The homotopy groups of spheres are calculable in finite time, but the complexity is so high that nobody could do in practice, even with the help of computers.

Comment: See the paper "Pessimal Algorithms and Simplexity Analysis" by Andrei Broder and Jorge Stolfi, http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.116.9158%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=1CnVTer2McPIgQfrqrT-Cw&usg=AFQjCNHzV6ePqxfVjE0b_qoDC0WaygUqMQ&sig2=9gkA3pG4ANuyeBX8tTEgqw


Comment: See also CSTheory: 
"Polynomial-time algorithms with huge exponent"
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/

Comment: An updated link for  "Pessimal Algorithms and Simplexity Analysis" by Andrei Broder and Jorge Stolfi is https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/990534.990536.

Answer (score 8):

Of course there can be no "worst" algorithm, since for any
algorithm taking $p(n)$ steps on input of size $n$, we can
easily design another algorithm taking $2^{p(n)}$ steps,
which will be worse by the big-$O$ and big-$\Theta$
measures.

Meanwhile, the phenomenon of extremely long-running
computations is naturally related to the phenomenon of
fast-growing functions, such as the [Ackermann diagonal
function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function),
whose values---and hence whose running times---are
extremely large in comparison with conventional algorithms.

For example, here is an algorithm that is likely to be
worse than any algorithm you may have considered. The
problem is to determine, on input $n$, the $A(n)$-th digit
of the decimal expansion of $\pi$, where $A(n)$ is the
Ackermann diagonal function. On input $n$, my proposed
algorithm would first compute $A(n)$, and then compute
$\pi$ to that many digits, and then output the
corresponding digit. The running time of this algorithm
will exceed the Ackermann diagonal function, but it is not
clear how one could improve the algorithm to make it
faster.

But perhaps you meant to inquire merely about feasible
algorithms, that is, algorithms that we will actually want
to undertake. In this case, of course, even the exponential
algorithms that seem to be required for NP problems would
be too hard, and we would want to stay within the
polynomial hierarchy. Even $n^3$ algorithms are not really
feasible on large input.

(But indeed, I go further, if you are truly interested only
in actually feasible, practical algorithms, then the
big-$O$ and big-$\Theta$ concepts are not the right
concept, since even constant time $O(1)$ algorithms can be
unfeasible, if the constant is very large. The whole point
of big-$O$ and big-$\Theta$ is to look at asymptotic
behavior of the algorithms on extremely large input, and
this takes us immediately out of the actually feasible
category.)

Comment: @Joel: Concerning your first sentence, wouldn't it be more natural to focus on the time complexity of any algorithm that solves a particular problem, rather than on the time complexity of a specific algorithm? So usually a quoted $\Theta()$ bound means that no algorithm can do better, and some algorithm achieves that bound.

Comment: Joseph, the running-time concept is a feature of the algorithm, not of the problem that the algorithm solves. Indeed, we very rarely have information about the best possible time bound to solve a given problem. For example, knowing such information for certain problems would enable us to solve the P vs. NP problem.

Comment: In particular, I dispute your claim that a quoted $\Theta()$ bound means that it is known that no algorithm can do better---we very rarely know such information. Rather, a quoted $\Theta()$ bound describes the known running time of a particular proposed algorithm. 

Comment: @Joel: I should have said: "...no algorithm, under a particular model of computation."  For example, sorting has a lower bound of $\Omega( n \log n)$ in the algebraic decision-tree model, and various algorithms
achieve $O( n \log n )$ and so are claimed as $\Theta(n \log n)$.

Comment: An algorithm is correctly claimed as $\Theta(\cdot)$  if that is the asymptotic running time of that particular algorithm. It has nothing to do with whether there are other, quicker algorithms for the same problem. For exampe, my algorithm above has time complexity $\Theta(a(n))$, where $a(n)$ is the time to compute $A(n)$, even though I have no idea if there might be a quicker algorithm.

Comment: @Joel: I accept your point---You are correct! 
In practice one cares about matching
a lower bound on all algorithms under a particular model with an upper bound.  And this is often the route to $\Theta()$.

Comment: Yes, I think that is right.

Comment: @Joel, re: "it is not clear how one could improve the algorithm to make it faster." As soon as $n>3$ a huge speedup will be provided by using a spigot algorithm, which computes individual digits of $\pi$ without computing the preceding digits. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe_formula

Comment: Tom, yes, that would be faster, a polynomial time speed-up. But 
this is a actually a very mild improvement in light of the huge cost of computing $A(n)$, which dominates this algorithm. After all, the Ackermann function grows so rapidly that $A(n)$, $\log(A(n))$, $2^{A(n)}$ and even $2\uparrow A(n)$ all seem basically in the same ballpark (for example, these differences matter far far less than simply going to $A(n\pm 1)$), and so it is the difficulty of computing $A(n)$ that matters here, swamping any difficulty of computing $\pi$.

Comment: There's no reason that computing the A(n)th digit of pi necessarily requires computing A(n). That would be like saying that computing A(n) mod 2 requires computing A(n), which it doesn't seem to (it appears to always be 1, but I haven't done all the necessary math.) Both are of the form f(A(n)). I agree that there's probably no shared structure, but that doesn't lead to a proof that there's no shared structure.

Answer (score 6):

Tarski's decision procedure for sentences in the first-order theory of real closed fields

[users.cs.duke.edu/~reif/paper/benor/realclosed.pdf](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Ereif/paper/benor/realclosed.pdf)

Comment: Isn't it the case that in Tarski's original formulation, the complexity is not even elementary recursive?

Comment: Thierry, Tarski's original algorithm was an elimination of quantifiers argument: given a sentence, he applied his recursive quantifier elimination procedure and ended up with a quantifier-free assertion, whose truth can be easily decided. This makes his original algorithm definitely recursive, even primitive recursive, but it was horribly iterated exponential time.

Comment: @Thierry: Yes, that's what the article says.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, but it does not make it elementary recursive.

Comment: Ah, I see now that "elementary recursive" is a very limited class: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY. 

Answer (score 6):

I think the question needs to be sharpened to exclude algorithms that compute
(or even involve)
combinatorially complex structures.
For example, the convex hull of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ has size $\Theta(n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor})$
for fixed $d$.
There is an asymptotically optimal algorithm (due to Chazelle (1)) to compute this hull
in time $O( n \log n + n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor} )$.
So one could exceed any power of $n$ in the time complexity by selection of a sufficiently
large $d$.

So you need to specify that the algorithm is a decision procedure,
outputting only one bit, *Yes* or *No*.
But even here, there is no upper bound on the "worst" algorithm time complexity.

Again consider the convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d$ fixed, and ask:
(a) Is the hull simplicial?
or (b) Does the hull have exactly $F$ facets?
Jeff Erickson showed (2) that, even for these decision questions,
$\Omega( n \log n + n^{\lceil d/2 \rceil -1} )$ time is needed,
matching the known upper bounds for odd $d$.

---

(1) Bernard Chazelle.
"[An optimal convex hull algorithm in any fixed dimension](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02573985)."
*Discrete & Computational Geometry*,
Volume 10 (1993), Number 4, 377–409.
[Zbl 0786.68091](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0786.68091)

(2) Jeff Erickson.
"[New Lower Bounds for Convex Hull Problems in Odd Dimensions](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539797315410)."
*SIAM J. Comput.*, 28 (1999), 1198–1214.
[Zbl 0939.68047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0939.68047)

---

An irrelevant aside: I coauthored an algorithm with time complexity $O(n^{42})$. :-)